# hear of Vs hear about

Tags: grammar

Is *to hear of* perfectly synonymous with *to hear about*? Or are there contexts in which one excludes the other?

Hearing *of*... is great news.

Hearing *about*... is great news.

Comment: I can hear about 5 people coming to tell you that they're not perfect synonyms

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Know about" vs. "know of"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29869/know-about-vs-know-of)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To *[hear of](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/hear+of#hear__145)* something is to become aware of it, whereas to *hear about* something is to be informed about it, for example, to receive news about it:

> Have you heard of John Key? *[i.e. do you know who John Key is?]*
>
> Have you heard about John Key? *[i.e. have you heard the news involving John Key?]*
>
> I heard of a new restaurant in the Gaslamp Quarter. *[i.e. I have learned that there is a new restaurant.]*
>
> I heard about a new restaurant in the Gaslamp Quarter. *[i.e. somebody told me about a new restaurant (and she wouldn't shut up about it for three trolley stops).]*

A similar distinction exists with [*knowing of* and *knowing about*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29869), *telling of* / *telling about*, and similar pairs of verbs about information transmission.