# to know vs to know about

Tags: differences

Is there any difference between "to know" and "to know about" when they refer to an abstract thing? Examples:

- I know (about) this difficulty/problem.
- I know (about) Engineering.

In the first sentence, it seems to me that "to know" expresses that the speaker experienced the problem/difficulty before while "to know about" only expresses that the speaker has heard or read about it. In the second sentence, it seems to me that "to know" expresses a deeper knowledge than "to know about". Are those impressions correct?

This is NOT a duplicate of "["Know about" vs. "know of"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29869/know-about-vs-know-of)", which focus only on "to know about" and "to know of".

Comment: Worth reading first: [know about vs know of](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29869/know-about-vs-know-of)

Comment: I have already read it, but it doesn't answer this question.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd ever use "I know this difficulty" (other than in the literary "We have known/experienced hard times" sense).

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Know about" vs. "know of".](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29869/know-about-vs-know-of) Also [What are the differences between “know”, “know about”, and “know of”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-the-differences-between-know-know-about-and-know-of) on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), which is probably a better site for questions like this.

Comment: Alan - I think answers on both the ELL and ELU questions make it perfectly clear that *to know X* usually implies you have *personal, in-depth* knowledge, whereas *to know **about / of** X* often simply means *to be **aware** of X* (perhaps knowing little more than that X does in fact exist).

Comment: "She knows engineering inside out" and "She knows all about engineering" are more idiomatic, and largely synonymous.

Comment: @FumbleFingers there is nothing in the 1st question about "to know" besides its meaning of "to be acquainted with someone", the focus is of that question is on "to know about" and "to know of". On the other hand, https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-the-differences-between-know-know-about-and-know-of indeed answers my question. My question cam be closed as a duplicate of it.

Comment: I can't entirely agree with that. The second answer on the earlier ELU question says including ***about*** specifically implies *knowledge of a specific event or characteristic related [to X]* (as opposed to being personally acquainted with X in the more general sense). But as you imply, the answers to that other ELL question are likely to be more suited to learners (that ***is*** why the site exists, after all! :) But since we're on ELU anyway, you might want to look at [this answer of mine](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/71019/2637) to a very closely-related question.

Answer (score 1):

I know about electrical engineering -- I've read about it a few times and know more or less what it is.

I know electrical engineering -- I have a degree in the subject and know how to do engineering stuff.

I know about his pain -- I've seen him limp and I've heard him complain.

I know his pain -- I have similar pains myself and know what he's going through.

Answer (score -1):

*To know* is when the *knowing* is of the person talking.

*To know about* is external; it has happened to someone/thing else.